# C# Клик мыши в неактивном окне

Tags: c#, winapi, click, мышь

Как сделать клик мыши по кординатам в не активном окне?

для игры на движке DirectX

игра сделана в Unity, скомпилирована в машинный код (C++)

Для WinAPI я использую библиотеку: [MemorySharp](https://github.com/ZenLulz/MemorySharp)

Пробывал:

```
Point move = new Point(450, 365);
MemorySharp sharp = new MemorySharp(process);
Binarysharp.MemoryManagement.Windows.RemoteWindow window = sharp.Windows.MainWindow;
window.SendMessage(Binarysharp.MemoryManagement.Native.WindowsMessages.LButtonDown, UIntPtr.Zero, CreateLParam(move));
window.SendMessage(Binarysharp.MemoryManagement.Native.WindowsMessages.LButtonUp, UIntPtr.Zero, CreateLParam(move));
sharp.Dispose();
```

Метод CreateLParam

```
public static IntPtr CreateLParam(Point point)
{
    return (IntPtr)((point.X << 16) | (point.Y & 0xffff));
}
```

Пробывал №2:

```
window.PostMessage(Binarysharp.MemoryManagement.Native.WindowsMessages.LButtonDown, UIntPtr.Zero, (UIntPtr)(move.X & (move.Y << 16)));
window.PostMessage(Binarysharp.MemoryManagement.Native.WindowsMessages.LButtonUp, UIntPtr.Zero, (UIntPtr)(move.X & (move.Y << 16)));
```

Comment: P/Invoke `SendInput` или `mouse_event` вам поможет.

Comment: Приложите код к вопросу текстом

Comment: @aepot mouse_event делает клик по всему экрану а не только в определенном окне

Comment: @Voprositel приложил.

Comment: Так определите координаты окна и кликайте по нужному окну.

Comment: @aepot мне нужно делать клик по кординатам в окне которое свернуто без разворачивания окна

Comment: Кстати, что за приложение, не DirectX игра случаем? Если да, то ничего не получится.

Comment: @aepot да приложение DirectX игра

Comment: Тогда, сожалею, DirectX приложение принимает на вход только реальный ввод и не обрабатывает Windows сообщения так, как это делает обычное приложение. Поэтому получится только через SendInput, но как вы уже поняли, окно придется для этого развернуть.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542378/12888024) еще что нашел.